# How to find the maximum consecutive, negative sum in an array?

Tags: python, arrays, algorithm, time-complexity

What is the most efficient way to calculate the most negative sum for any set of consecutive indexes in an array? You can take any consecutive group of positive and negative integers in an array to create the most negative sum possible.

For example you have `arr = [10, -15, 2, 25, -16, -53, 22, 2, 1, -3, 60]` the most negative sum is -69 from summing -16 and -53.

Another example you have `arr = [10, -15, -2, 10, -16, -53, 22, 2, 1, -3, 60]` the most negative sum is -76 from summing -15, -2, 10, -16, -53.

Comment: You can use a modified version of [Kadane's Algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maximum_subarray_problem#Kadane's_algorithm).

Comment: you need to modified Kadane's algorithm

Comment: sum value of -15, -2, 10, -16, -53 is -76, not -78

Comment: yeah sorry it's late by me :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the standard [Kadane’s algorithm](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/largest-sum-contiguous-subarray/), just change the sign of array element.

```
def kadane(arr):
    max_so_far = float('-inf')
    max_ending_here = 0

    for i in range(0, len(arr)):
        arr[i] = arr[i] * -1
        max_ending_here = max_ending_here + arr[i]
        if max_so_far < max_ending_here:
            max_so_far = max_ending_here

        if max_ending_here < 0:
            max_ending_here = 0
    return max_so_far


print(kadane(arr=[10, -15, 2, 25, -16, -53, 22, 2, 1, -3, 60]) * -1)  # -69
print(kadane(arr=[10, -15, -2, 10, -16, -53, 22, 2, 1, -3, 60]) * -1) # -76
```